# How can set up the table correctly for receiving the string converted from dates?

Tags: date, easyphp

I have a problem and don't know how to solve it. After i run the code i didn't receive corectly a period of time. I put the code here.

I think something is wrong with table from database (i use PhpMyAdmin 4.2.0 module from EasyPhp). I put an image too to see what happens. The dates marked with red need to be at the end of table.

```
<?php

function data_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output - format = 'd-m-Y')
    {
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);
    while ($current <= $last)
        {
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
        }

    foreach($dates as $zile)
        {
        $krr = explode('-', $zile);
        var_dump($krr);
        $result2 = implode('/', $krr);
        echo $result2 . "<br/>";
        $sql4 = "INSERT INTO studenti3 (data) VALUES ('$result2')";
        $rez4 = mysql_query($sql4);
        }

    var_dump($dates);
    }

$first = "06-04-2015";
$last = "07-05-2015";
$step = "+1day";
$output_format = 'd-m-Y';
date_range($first, $last, $step, $output_format); ?>
```

Comment: Can't add image. i dont have reputation point. I can explain here. The date in table come right that: 01/05/2015, 02/05/2015, 03/05/2015, 04/05/2015, 05/05/2015, now come 06/04/2015, 06/05/2015, 07/04/2015, 07/05/2015, 08/04/2015, 09/04/2015... and so on. Don't know why is coming like that. I want to come in order to table from 06/04/2015 to 07/05/2015. Thanks!

Comment: lucky can u show me how u organize the code like this?